# Validating datasets produced by identical Apache airflows

Tags: validation, airflow, great-expectations

I have the same workflow on two different environments. To validate that both workflows are identical, I feed the same input data to both workflows. If they are identical, I am expecting the output dataset of each workflow to be same.

In this requirement, I cannot alter the workflow in any way (add/remove DAG's etc.).

Which tool is best suited for this use case? I was reading up on data validation frameworks like Apache Griffin and Great Expectations. Can either of this be used for this use case? Or is there a simpler alternative?

Update: I forgot to mention that I want the validation process to be as non interactive as possible. Reading the [Great Expectations tutorial](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/tutorials/getting_started/tutorial_overview), it talks about manually opening & running Jupyter notebooks and I want to minimize processes like this as much as possible. If that makes sense.

Update 2:

Dataset produced by workflow in first environment:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 |
| DEF | 20 |

Dataset produced by workflow in second environment:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| DEF | 20 |
| ABC | 10 |

After running validation, I want the output to be that both datasets are identical even though they are in a different order.

Comment: Without seeing your output data or the final data store; it is difficult to make an informed answer. however, based on your requirements. I would be inclined to put them into a Pandas DF and compare.

Comment: @dimButTries for this initial requirement, it will most probably simple tabular data exported to CSV files stored locally on a disk or a cloud bucket. Will check out Pandas. Not entirely familiar with Python yet but working on it

Comment: @dimButTries please check Update 2 in my question for a simplified idea on the planned datasets.

Comment: Thank you for preparing an example is the name unique in both datasets?

Comment: @dimButTries Nope. Name is a non unique column